# Socket InputStream's first read call is taking more time

Tags: sockets, inputstream

I am trying to read the bytes from the `inputstream` we get from Socket as below.

```
URL u = new URL("http://admdemo.triniti.com/tabimpl/jsp/basicjsp/logon.jsp");
Socket s = new Socket(u.getHost(), 80);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(theOutput, false);
pw.print("GET " + u.getFile() + " HTTP/1.0\r\n");
pw.print("Accept: text/plain, text/html, text/*\r\n");
pw.print("\r\n");
pw.flush();
InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
int c;
while((c = isr.read()) != - 1)
{
    System.out.print("TIME taken to read byte : " (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
}
```

When executed, the first byte read call time is showing in around `~400-500ms`, but all the subsequent read calls taking `0ms`. Can someone help me on why it is taking that much time?
If that is the default behavior of java io, then do we have any other ways to implement the same in a better way?